# Foreach -parallel object

Tags: powershell, workflow, parallel.foreach

Recently we started working on scripts that take a very long time to complete. So we dug into PowerShell workflows. After reading some documentation I understand the basics. However, I can't seem to find a way to create a `[PSCustomObject]` for each individual item within a `foreach -parallel` statement.

**Some code to explain:**

```
Workflow Test-Fruit {

    foreach -parallel ($I in (0..1)) {

        # Create a custom hashtable for this specific object
        $Result = [Ordered]@{
            Name  = $I
            Taste = 'Good'
            Price = 'Cheap'
        }

        Parallel {
            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $Result += @{'Color' = 'Green'}
            }

            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $Result += @{'Fruit' = 'Kiwi'}
            }
        }

        # Generate a PSCustomObject to work with later on
        [PSCustomObject]$Result
    }
}

Test-Fruit
```

The part where it goes wrong is in adding a value to the `$Result` hashtable from within the `Sequence` block. Even when trying the following, it still fails:

```
$WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Fruit' = 'Kiwi'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here you go, tried and tested:

```
Workflow Test-Fruit {

    foreach -parallel ($I in (0..1)) {

        # Create a custom hashtable for this specific object
        $WORKFLOW:Result = [Ordered]@{
            Name  = $I
            Taste = 'Good'
            Price = 'Cheap'
        }

        Parallel {

            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Color' = 'Green'}
            }

            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Fruit' = 'Kiwi'}
            }


        }

        # Generate a PSCustomObject to work with later on
        [PSCustomObject]$WORKFLOW:Result
    }
}

Test-Fruit
```

You're supposed to define it as $WORKFLOW:var and repeat that use throughout the workflow to access the scope.

Comment: This is fully awesome! And exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Thom, great answer! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Is writing to the $WORKFLOW:Result from parallel operations thread safe? In the case of a foreach -parallel block running an inlinescript it seems that they both could try to access this variable at the same time to write their results.

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland very good question, I haven't seen this addressed anywhere. My guess is that it does get synchronized somehow to be thread safe by PowerShell otherwise the whole `$workflow` scope would be somewhat useless.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign `$Result` to the output of the `Parallel` block and add the other properties afterwards :

```
$Result = Parallel {
    Sequence {
        # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
        [Ordered]@{'Color' = 'Green'}                    
    }

    Sequence {
        # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
       [Ordered] @{'Fruit' = 'Kiwi'}
    }
}

# Generate a PSCustomObject to work with later on
$Result += [Ordered]@{
    Name  = $I
    Taste = 'Good'
    Price = 'Cheap'
}

# Generate a PSCustomObject to work with later on
[PSCustomObject]$Result
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Martin. But I can't seem to get ti to convert properly to a `PCCustomObject` this way. It still outputs as a `HashTable`

Comment: You are right, its probably because the type of the hashtable is a`Deserialized.System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`. But don't know how to solve this...