# PowerShell Workflow reference script variables

Tags: powershell, variables, workflow

The following code works fine thanks to [Thom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881875/powershell-workflow-foreach-parallel-object/37882873#37882873):

```
Workflow Test-Fruit {
    foreach -parallel ($I in (0..1)) {
        # Create a custom hashtable for this specific object
        $WORKFLOW:Result = [Ordered]@{
            Name  = $I
            Taste = "Good $I"
            Price = "Cheap $I"
        }

        Parallel {
            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Color' = "Green $I"}
            }
            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Fruit' = "Kiwi $I"}
            }
        }

        # Generate a PSCustomObject to work with later on
        [PSCustomObject]$WORKFLOW:Result
    }
}
Test-Fruit
```

But when I try to add another variable in the parent scope, to be used later on in some of the `Sequence` blocks, this fails:

```
Workflow Test-Fruit {
    foreach -parallel ($I in (0..1)) {
        # Create a custom hashtable for this specific object
        $WORKFLOW:Result = [Ordered]@{
            Name  = $I
            Taste = "Good $I"
            Price = "Cheap $I"
        }

        $WORKFLOW:Files = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\

        Parallel {
            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Color' = "Green $I"}

                if ($I -eq 0) {
                    # Do smething with Files
                    $WORKFLOW:Files.Name | Select-Object -First 1
                }
            }
            Sequence {
                # Add a custom entry to the hashtable
                $WORKFLOW:Result += @{'Fruit' = "Kiwi $I"}

                if ($I -eq 1) {
                    # Do smething with Files
                    $WORKFLOW:Files.Name | Select-Object -Last 1
                }
            }
        }

        # Generate a PSCustomObject to work with later on
        [PSCustomObject]$WORKFLOW:Result
    }
}
Test-Fruit
```

With the following error:

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Color'  Key being
>   added: 'Color' Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Fruit'
>   Key being added: 'Fruit'

How can I define another script variable so to speak and then use it in the `Sequence` blocks?

Comment: This is a race condition - without the delay from enumerating the files with `Get-ChildItem`, the first outer `foreach -parallel` block executes and returns before the next one is invoked - it's still prone to fail. Try and add a short delay (`Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 100` for example) in one of the `sequence` blocks and you'll see that it fails even without `$WORKFLOW:Files`

Comment: Thank you Mathias, you are correct. How can I have one specific object for each item in the `foreach -parallel` loop? This has to be possible, no?

Comment: It is, if you remove the inline `Parallel` block. What is the motivation behind attempting nested parallelism like this?

Comment: The activities executed in the `foreach -parallel` clause are executed in sequence, meaning first line first and then the second... The activities executed in the `Parallel` clause are executed in parallel, meaning the order isn't important and can even be run side by side. So the code in the `Sequence` blocks will be code that can be run in parallel with the other `Sequence` blocks.

Comment: Basically, I'm just collecting a lot of information in the `Sequence` blocks. After they are all executed in parallel, I would like to take a decision on that combined collected input.

Comment: Yes, I know how `Parallel` and `Sequence` behaves, I'm asking *why* you need to process individual properties of each object in parallel? Have you found that it's unacceptably slow if not?

Comment: I'm just rewriting a script that takes a long time to complete to a workflow. When doing this I'd like to do as much as possible in parallel, as this speeds up the process a lot. It just seems a tremendous difficulty to have one `PSCustomObject` as output per item in case you use `Parallel` and `Sequance` blocks.